Do you say "pimples" or "zits" just for acne or for many other spotted skin condition as well?
I remember when I was 14 or 15, I had many spots on my neck and face. When I popped them, white mucus came out. I think I had acne back then.

(Source)
When it is very hot, my skin has some small red spots which I can not pop. I think I have heat rash, which is common on babies.

(Source)
In everyday English, Do you say directly "I have acne/ heat rash etc"?
or Do you say "I have pimples/ zits / spots" for acne only or for other skin conditions too such as heat rash?
I guess people don;t have I have pimples when they have heat rash.
Also, there are many other skin conditions that you don't know their technical names. In that case, do you say "pimples/ zits / spots" for them?

A few moments' googling showed me that pimples are the infected ones you get from acne and zits is a slang word for these. Spots are any kind of red 'dot' on the skin.

Acne
Acne is a condition. If you are talking about the condition, you might say:

I have acne.


My acne is really bad this week.


My acne has cleared up.

(All of these phrases can also apply to many other chronic conditions such as a rash.)
When talking about the specific marks that make up acne, the more formal term is pimple and the less formal/slang term is zit. You can use these words in the singular or in the plural:

I have a painful pimple on my chin.


I commonly get pimples on my chin.

Spots
A spot is a more general term, usually used when you don't know the cause or what it is. For example:

I sometimes get red spots on my hand. Do you think it could be a rash?


I have a dark spot on my leg. I'm not sure how it got there.

In most cases, spot can be substituted for dot or sometimes for splotch.
Other conditions
Typically if you know what a condition is, you would refer to it as such. For example, here is how you would talk about a rash:

I have an itchy rash on my elbows.


My skin is red because I have a rash.


I have to put cream on my rash.

Other conditions would be refered to specifically as well. Some other examples might include:

eczema
bug bites


I don't doubt that a medical professional would make a distinction between acne and other skin conditions. But to the average person, anything that causes pimples is called "acne". There are many words that have technical definitions that are more precise than the common definition. It is not wrong to use the vaguer meaning in general conversation. It would be wrong to use it in a technical conversation where the distinction matters.
